# operator * cannot be applied to operands C#

Tags: c#

Trying to make a Loan Application and i Am getting this as errors

> operator * cannot be applied to operands of type textbox and int
>   operator * cannot be applied to operands of type textbox and double

My code Looks Like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp3
{
    public partial class LoanApplication : Form
    {
        double InterestRate, monthlyInterestRate, loanAmount, monthlyPayment, TotalPayment;
        int NoOfyears;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InterestRate = Convert.ToDouble(rate.Text);
            monthlyInterestRate = InterestRate / 1200;
            NoOfyears = Convert.ToInt32(noOfYrs.Text);
            loanAmount = Convert.ToDouble(txtLoanAmt.Text);

            monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,noOfYrs * 12)); // This Line

            iMonthlyPayment = Convert.ToString(monthlyPayment);
            iMonthlyPayment = String.Format("{0:C}", monthlyPayment);
            monthly_payment.Text = (iMonthlyPayment);

            TotalPayment = monthlyPayment * noOfYrs * 12; // This Line
            iTotalPayment = String.Format("{0:C}", TotalPayment);
            total_payment.Text = (iTotalPayment);

            txtLoanAmt.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", txtLoanAmt.Text);
        }

        string iMonthlyPayment, iTotalPayment;
        public LoanApplication()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void LoanApplication_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly am I Missing here?

Comment: Which part of the error message seems unclear?

Comment: @mustaccio This Line **monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,noOfYrs * 12)); ** and This Line **TotalPayment = monthlyPayment * noOfYrs * 12;**

Comment: In C#, identifiers are case-sensitive.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code - clearly wall of code in this post is way more than necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the problematic line you are using the variable `noOfYrs`, which is a TextBlock, instead of `NoOfyears`, which is an integer.

Comment: Think That Solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do textbox * int. Textbox is object and you can  not multiply it by int it Double. You need to get value from textbox first and cast it int int or Double. Eg. int.Parse(myTextbox.Text) * myInt

Comment: `(int)myTextbox.Text` :))

Comment: Dude, that is wrong. You meant int.Parse(myText.Text) or Convert...

Comment: Yes my bad. I fixed that